# Mock a json in c# to unit test

Tags: c#, json, mocking

I am currently trying to unit test the code below and don't really know where to go with it. After reading up a bit I think I need to use mocking/faking and initialize a fake json directory that I can pass through to the unit tests, although mocking seems really complicated and I cant seem to get my head around it. Any help on this would be amazing.
Thanks in advance,
K

```
        public static string ShowLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +  @"\Database\Shows.txt";
    public static string GoldMemberLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Database\GoldMembers.txt";

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes a specific show from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="show"></param>
    public static void DeleteShow (Show show)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(ShowLocation))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(ShowLocation);

            List<Show> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Show>>(json);
            data.Remove(show);

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(ShowLocation, json);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(ShowLocation, String.Empty);
            SaveShow(show);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves a new Show.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="show"></param>
    public static void SaveShow(Show show)
    {
        if (File.Exists(ShowLocation))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(ShowLocation);

            var data = new List<Show>();

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(ShowLocation);
            if (f.Length > 0)
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Show>>(json);
            }

            data.Add(show);

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(ShowLocation, json); 
        }
        else
        { 
            var data = new List<Show>();

            data.Add(show);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(ShowLocation, json);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads all the shows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Show> LoadShows()
    {
        if (File.Exists(ShowLocation))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(ShowLocation);

            List<Show> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Show>>(json);

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(ShowLocation, String.Empty);
            return new List<Show>();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes a specific gold member.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="goldMember"></param>
    public static void DeleteGoldMember(GoldMember goldMember)
    {
        if (File.Exists(GoldMemberLocation))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(GoldMemberLocation);

            List<GoldMember> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GoldMember>>(json);
            data.Remove(goldMember);

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(GoldMemberLocation, json);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(GoldMemberLocation, String.Empty);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves a new Gold member
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="goldMember"></param>
    public static void SaveGoldMembers (GoldMember goldMember)
    {

        if (File.Exists(GoldMemberLocation))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(GoldMemberLocation);
            var data = new List<GoldMember>();

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(GoldMemberLocation);
            if (f.Length > 0)
            {
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GoldMember>>(json);
            }

            data.Add(goldMember);

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(GoldMemberLocation, json);
        }
        else
        {
            var data = new List<GoldMember>();
            data.Add(goldMember);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            File.WriteAllText(GoldMemberLocation, json);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code is tightly coupled to static IO implementation concerns, which, while not impossible to test does force you to have physical files to exercise the tests.  Encapsulate IO calls behind an abstraction to decouple and separate concerns so that code is easier to test in isolation.

Comment: @Nkosi would it be possible to give an example or link somewhere for me to read up on this?

Comment: This is  your data layer which has limited potential to be unit tested. I would probably cover this code with integration tests as opposed to unit tests. However, it should be refactored to be interfaced and not static so it can be injected into your business logic layer where you would do the bulk of your unit testing. You can see Stuart's answer has limited use since all you can really do is assert your method was called, it is not really exercising any logic.

Comment: It's exercising logic in that it could be set up to test that if he passes in a directory that doesn't exist, he can assert that a file is created in that location and it's empty. Similar if it does exist, he can assert that it calls the method but passes in the correct contents. That's the only logic in that method... I would agree though, if it's a data layer, I woudl cover it with integration tests too. Sure, you can test that the File.WriteAllLines works, but it's  .net library method. if you're testing hte .net framework you're doing it wrong.. Similar, no need to test JSonConvert....

Answer (score 1):

Ok,the things stopped you testing it is the File IO. So you need to pull these methods to an interface and then mock that interface.

Then setup what you want those mocked methods to return.

e.g.

```
// A concrete implementation you will use at runtime.
public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
{
    bool DirectoryExists(string location) => Directory.Exists(location);
    string ReadAlltext(string location) => File.ReadAllText(location);
    void WriteAlLText(string location, string text) => File.WriteAlLText(location, text);
}

public interface IFileHelper
{
    bool DirectoryExists(string location);
    string ReadAlltext(string location);
    WriteAllText(string location, string text);
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestDeleteShow()
{
    // Create a mock of your FileHelper and setup
    // the methods and what you want them to return.
    Mock<IFileHelper> fileHelper = new Mock<IFileHelper>();
    fileHelper.Setup(x=>x.DirectoryExists).Returns(true);
    fileHelper.Setup(x=>x.ReadAllText).Returns( /* put some text in here */);
    string testLocation = "foo";
    Foo.DeleteShow(testLocation);

    // Verify the methods on your mock were called, as expected.
    fileHelper.Verify(x=>x.WriteAlLText(It.IsAny<string>(), string.Empty));
}
```

You can then verify that certain methods were called with certain parameters. My example is using Moq.

e.g., you can setup a test where DirectoryExists returns false, and then you can verify that File.WriteAllText was called with an empty string and the correct location. etc

A comment above says this doesnt test any logic... It's exercising logic in that it could be set up to test that if he passes in a directory that doesn't exist, you can assert that a file is created in that location and it's empty. Similar if it does exist, you can assert that it calls the method but passes in the correct contents.

That's the only logic in that method... Sure, you can test that the File.WriteAllLines works, but it's a .net library method. if you're testing the .net framework you're doing it wrong.. Similar, no need to test JSonConvert.... In the method I gave you an example of, you are testing the logic that you get a different action based on wether a directory exists, that's the only logic in that method....